# Codeigniter insert data results in PHP warning

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, warnings

I have a problem with my Codeigniter appclication at work.
I'm using a virtual Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS, MSSQL and PHP

When I try to insert new records in the database, I get the following warning (for each insert):

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
>
> Filename: sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 423

The code I'm using:

```
$data = array(
                'DataTypeSpecification'         => $dataTypeSpecID,
                'DocumentCode'                  => $docCode,
                'Title'                         => $title,
                'ProjectCode'                   => $projectCode, 
                'Process'                       => $process, 
                'Author'                        => $author,
                'Status'                        => $status,
                'Version'                       => $version, 
                'DateApproval'                  => $dateApproval,
                'Medium'                        => $medium, 
                'PaperArchivedDate'             => $paperArchivedDate, 
                'DMSArchivedDate'               => $DMSArchivedDate,
                'EDocDocument'                  => $eDocDocument,
                'Wildcard'                      => $wildcard, 
                'SequentialNumber'              => $seqNumber, 
                'Location'                      => $location, 
                'ArchivedShelf'                 => $archivedShelf,
                'Container'                     => $container, 
                'Remarks'                       => $remakrs, 
                'APDProjectStatus'              => $APDProjectStatus, 
                'SelectedForIND'                => $selectedForIND);

$result = $this->db->insert('dbo.ProjectRecords', $data);
return $result;
```

All of the variables are set correctly.
Here is the funny thing. It seems that everything gets inserted correctly in the database...

Anyone knows why this warning is displayed?

Regards
Nicolai

Comment: Can't see `array_shift()` anywhere on the code ..

Comment: uumm because there is an array_shift function being used. But it is not being passed a value... We wouldn't be able to know what it is doing without seeing it. But it isn't doing anything "BAD" by that warning. It just isn't doing anything.

Comment: Can you do a search and find the array_shift and post the code for the function that it is in...

Comment: The code containing `array_shift()` is from CI's sqlsrv driver. Specifically from the `_error_number()` function. Are you doing anything else with `$result` after the posted code?

Comment: Good call Samutz, sorry the coffee isn't kicking in this morning.

Comment: @Samutz I really don't need to return the result. Thou I still need to know if any error occurs - like dup keys. I guess I can use _error_message or _error_number for that?

Comment: Well _error_message() isn't working though. If it were, you'd be getting a SQL error of some sort since the driver is trying to call it. I think there's a problem with your sqlsrv driver. Have you modified it?

Comment: Nope, havent touch the driver. Why ain't _error_message() working? I have used it in same context with fine results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I had to edit the driver itself.
I changed the file `system/database/sqlsrv/sqlsrv_driver.php`
The two functions `_error_message()` (line 407) and `_error_number()` (line 423)

In both of them, i changed the first two lines to:

```
$tmp = sqlsrv_errors();
if($tmp == null) return null;
$error = array_shift($tmp);
```

So that i.e. `_error_number()` becomes:

```
function _error_number()
{
    $tmp = sqlsrv_errors();
    if($tmp == null) return null;
    $error = array_shift($tmp);
    return isset($error['SQLSTATE']) ? $error['SQLSTATE'] : null;
}
```

The error occurs since `sqlsrv_errors()` returns `NULL`, and when passing `NULL` to the `array_shift()` method, baaad things happens!